# AS3: How do I play a sound when the currentframe ==?

Tags: actionscript-3

My code below unfortunately results in the sound repeating at the framerate of the movie. I just need a simple "play a sound at a specific frame" function but can't figure this one out. Thanks for your help.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,soundFunction);
function soundFunction(event:Event)
{
if (naturepage.ocean_btns.currentFrame == 2)
{
    ocean_channel.stop();
    ocean_channel = ocean1.play(0,int.MAX_VALUE);
    mySO.data.ocean = "2";
    mySO.flush();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems about right. Are you sure the `naturepage.ocean_btns` movieclip is not stopped at the second frame or looping very few frames over and over?

Another option is to use a flag to see if you already played the sound:

```
var alreadyPlayedSound:Boolean = false;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,soundFunction);
function soundFunction(event:Event)
{
    if (naturepage.ocean_btns.currentFrame == 2 && !alreadyPlayedSound)
    {
        alreadyPlayedSound = true;

        ocean_channel.stop();
        ocean_channel = ocean1.play(0,int.MAX_VALUE);
        mySO.data.ocean = "2";
        mySO.flush();
    }
}
```

Or to remove the event listener once you played the sound:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,soundFunction);
function soundFunction(event:Event)
{
    if (naturepage.ocean_btns.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        ocean_channel.stop();
        ocean_channel = ocean1.play(0,int.MAX_VALUE);
        mySO.data.ocean = "2";
        mySO.flush();

        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,soundFunction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I used your flag idea and implemented my shared objects since I have several frames that need to be repeated. It works great.